# MySQL with multiple timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Ok, an old hack is no longer working.  Currently using MySQL 5.5.11

In my table I have the below in the same order.

```
created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00
updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

On INSERT everything works correctly and NOW() is inserted on both created and updated

Now with MySQL 5.5.11 when I UPDATE, updated works correctly but I loose created (reverts back to 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

How can I overcome this limitation with MySQL's lack of multiple TIMESTAMP support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would work on earlier version, but not newer version. 
I believe you can solve this as follows:

```
`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

And then create an trigger BEFORE UPDATE on [updated] column.

```
SET new.updated = now();
```

Or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, `TIMESTAMP` columns get automatically updated on every `UPDATE` operation to a particular row. It looks like you need column `created` to be `DATETIME` instead of timestamp.